# Spring boot mongo - How to refer to document in other collections from a collection

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I have Office object:

```
class Office{
   String address;
   int employees;
   String city;
   String State;
   ---- lot of other fields
}
```

I have `mongo` collections for Office class that have lets say 100 Office documents represented by above Office class.

Then I have Employee class:

```
class Employee{
   String firstName;
   String lastName;
   Office office;
   -----other fields
}
```

In mongo collection for Employee class how I can prevent Office object to be copied for each Employee entry.

In `spring-boot mongodb` is there way I can refer to Office collection to represent Office object of Employee instead of copying it for each employee in mongo db. I hope I have explained my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the DBRef in Mongo. Spring Data brings an annotation for that:

`@DBRef`

But, be careful, MongoDB is a document-oriented NoSQL and is a good practice to embed stuff inside a document. This approach can lead you to a bigger problem.

**Edit:**

Use the  `@DBRef` like this:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.7.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#mapping-usage-references

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code which you can use:

```
@Document(collection="person")
public class Person
{

        @Id
        private Long personId;

        private String name;

        private int age;

        @DBRef(db="address")
        private List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<Address>();

//other getters and setters

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using your example as base:

```
@Document
class Employee {
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;

   @DBRef
   private Office office;

   /* other fields */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of references in MongoBD: Manual References and DBRefs. Actually [the official documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/database-references/) advises to use manual references for nearly every case.

Cases to use DBRefs:

- you need to reference documents from multiple collections
- you need to reference documents from another database

Otherwise use manual references.

Spring Data MongoDB support both types of references since version 3.3 when annotation [@DocumentReference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/3.4.0-M4/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/mapping/DocumentReference.html) was introduced.